# SurfaceCreated using SurfaceView not being called with navigation drawer and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, surfaceview

I'm using a custom SurfaceView class to attempt to draw bitmaps on the screen. Additionally, I am using a navigation drawer and fragments to switch out which SurfaceView is displayed. I know this part is working, because I set the background color to be different for each one and I see the color change. The problem is that surfaceCreated() is never called. I start my drawing thread for the SurfaceView in that method, so the thread never starts and the bitmap is never drawn.

Here is the part of my main activity that is relevant to the fragment switching:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if(position ==0) {
        fragment = new MapFragment();
    } else {
        fragment = new TempFragment();
    }
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(MapFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(appScreens[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}


public static class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    public static String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

    public MapFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_screen, container, false);
        MapSurfaceView bmpView = (MapSurfaceView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bmpView);
        bmpView.setMap(map);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Note: MapFragment and TempFragment are the same thing with different background colors.

Main activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#cccc" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

SurfaceView:

```
class MapSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    class MapThread extends Thread {

        private Context mContext;

        /**
         * Handle to the surface manager object we interact with
         */
        private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

        /*
         * State-tracking constants
         */
        public static final int STATE_PAUSE = 1;
        public static final int STATE_RUNNING = 2;

        /**
         * The state of the game. One of READY, RUNNING, PAUSE, LOSE, or WIN
         */
        private int mMode;

        /**
         * Indicate whether the surface has been created & is ready to draw
         */
        private boolean mRun = false;

        public MapThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context) {
            // get handles to some important objects
            mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            mContext = context;
        }

        /**
         * Starts the game, setting parameters for the current difficulty.
         */
        public void doStart() {
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                setState(STATE_RUNNING);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Pauses the physics update & animation.
         */
        public void pause() {
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                if (mMode == STATE_RUNNING) setState(STATE_PAUSE);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Restores game state from the indicated Bundle. Typically called when
         * the Activity is being restored after having been previously
         * destroyed.
         *
         * @param savedState Bundle containing the game state
         */
        public synchronized void restoreState(Bundle savedState) {
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                setState(STATE_PAUSE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (mRun) {
                Canvas c = null;
                try {
                    c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                        if (mMode == STATE_RUNNING)
                        doDraw(c);
                    }
                } finally {
                    // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                    // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                    // inconsistent state
                    if (c != null) {
                        mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Dump game state to the provided Bundle. Typically called when the
         * Activity is being suspended.
         *
         * @return Bundle with this view's state
         */
        public Bundle saveState(Bundle map) {
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
            }
            return map;
        }

        /**
         * Used to signal the thread whether it should be running or not.
         * Passing true allows the thread to run; passing false will shut it
         * down if it's already running. Calling start() after this was most
         * recently called with false will result in an immediate shutdown.
         *
         * @param b true to run, false to shut down
         */
        public void setRunning(boolean b) {
            mRun = b;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the game mode. That is, whether we are running, paused, in the
         * failure state, in the victory state, etc.
         *
         * @param mode one of the STATE_* constants
         */
        public void setState(int mode) {
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                mMode = mode;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Resumes from a pause.
         */
        public void unpause() {
            // Move the real time clock up to now
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
            }
            setState(STATE_RUNNING);
        }

        /**
         * Draws the ship, fuel/speed bars, and background to the provided
         * Canvas.
         */
        private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Bitmap mapBMP = map.getMapBitmap().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            //System.out.println(mapBMP.describeContents());
            canvas.setBitmap(mapBMP);
        }
    }

    private Map map = null;
    private Context mContext;
    private MapThread thread;

    private Object mPauseLock;
    private boolean mPaused;
    private boolean mFinished;
    private boolean running = false;

    public MapSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        // create thread only; it's started in surfaceCreated()
        thread = new MapThread(holder, context);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public MapThread getThread(){
        return thread;
    }

    public void setMap(Map map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public void onFinishInflate() {
        System.out.println("Inflated");
    }

    public void onAttachedToWindow(){
        System.out.println("Attached");
    }

    public void onDetachedFromWindow(){
        System.out.println("Detached");
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
        if (!hasWindowFocus) thread.pause();
        else thread.unpause();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        System.out.println("Surface created");
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        thread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SurfaceView layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.wrathfulape.supremacy.MainScreen$PlaceholderFragment">

    <com.wrathfulape.supremacy.MapSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/bmpView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that MapSurfaceView's constructor is being executed (put a log message there)?

Comment: @fadden : Yep, constructor is getting called as is onAttachedToWindow and onFinishInflate.